# Using the probability measure as the random variable also. Possible?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Maybe it's a pathetic question to a degree, but I was wondering about this when going through the definitions.

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$, can we use the measure $P$ again to define a (real) random variable $X: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathbb R, \, A \mapsto P(A)$?

Then the push forward measure $P_X$ would be: For a Borel measurable set $A \in \mathbb R$, we have $P_X(A)=P(P^{-1}(A))= ?$

Only sets that intersect with $[0,1]$ will have a non zero image under $P_X$ of course. And for those $A$, we have $P_X(A) = P_X(A \cap [0,1])$. I'm not really sure how to continue now. Can someone tell me what $P_X$ looks like?

Comment: Since you gave a warning that it might be a pathetic question. $X: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathbb R, \, A \mapsto P(A)$ makes sense as a function on ${\cal A}$. What is the $\sigma$-algebra on that new probability space that makes $X$ a measurable random variable? I stopped reading there.

Comment: @KurtG. it's simply the Borel measurable sets: $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$

Comment: That makes the space where your $X$ takes its values a measure space. Fine with me. To make $X$ a random variable we need a $\sigma$-algebra in the *domain* of $X\,.$ There was a comment by someone else that got deleted and gave a good hint how do do this, albeit using an overcomplicated notation. ***Hint***: take in ${\cal A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by $X\,.$ Looks weird since ${\cal A}$ already is a $\sigma$-algebra (a fact that we should ignore). How would you formulate the hint using notation?